# /etc/rc.local is missing from my headless ubuntu 18.04

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I am currently hosting a minecraft server on ubuntu server 18.04 LTS. I have a .sh script to start the server's java file, and I would like to run it at startup so that the minecraft server starts when the physical server boots. I wished to do this via /etc/rc.local. However, I do not see rc.local in that location. 
Is it in a different location for this version of ubuntu, or is there an entirely different method I should use to run this .sh at startup?

Answer (score 12):

There is no "/etc/rc.local" file on Ubuntu 18.04, but you can create it.

Create the file with a text editor:

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

Paste the following lines and replace "COMMANDS" with the commands to be executed at system startup:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
COMMANDS
exit 0
```

Add the execute permission on the file:

```
chmod +x /etc/rc.local
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did and it worked without enabling rc-local.service

Comment: You should use `sudo chmod u+x /etc/rc.local` (notice the `u+x`) instead of `sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local` (just `+x`) so that only the root 'u'ser gets executable access to this file, rather than anybody, which could be a security concern I think.

Answer (score 4):

Set a crontab for this

Make sure the file is executable:

```
chmod +x /path_to_you_file/your_file/file.sh
```

To edit crontab file:

```
crontab -e
```

Then add this:

```
@reboot  /path_to_you_file/your_file/file.sh
```

Comment: Set the cron as `root` user, or the task will be also deleted when its owner user is removed.

Answer (score 2):

rc.local is disabled by default. 
Enable by using this command

```
sudo systemctl enable rc-local.service
```

Comment: I got this error when using that command: The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy, RequiredBy, Also, Alias
settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance for template units).
This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.